# Variable transformation in evaluating a double integral

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, multiple-integral, jacobian, change-of-variable

Evaluate

$$\iint_R(x+y)\,dA$$

Where $R$ is the trapezoidal region with vertices at $(0,0),(5,0),(5/2,5/2)$ and $(5/2,−5/2)$, using the transformation $x=2u+3v$ and $y=2u−3v$.

**Approach**:

The Jacobian comes out to be $12$, and the region in the $u−v$ plane consists of the points $(0,0),(5/2,0),(5/2,5/6),(0,5/6)$ which is a rectangle, and therefore, the double integral $\iint_{R'}(4u)[J\,du\,dv]$ is simply $$48\int_{0}^{5/6}\int_{0}^{5/2}u\,du\,dv= 125.$$
However, the answer given is $125/4$.

To kind of "check" where my mistake is, I came up with a small test:

By putting $f=1$ in the variable transformation formula for double integrals, we get:
$$Area(R)=J\times Area(R')$$

However, in my case, area of the original region is $25/2$, whereas $12$*(area of the transformed region) is $25$.

So have I messed up in drawing the transformed region? Or somewhere else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your work is correct except for the points of the new region:

$$\begin{cases}
2u + 3v = 5/2\\
2u - 3v = 5/2
\end{cases}$$
yields the point $(5/4, 0)$ and
$$\begin{cases}
2u + 3v = 5\\
2u - 3v = 0
\end{cases}
$$
gives the point $(5/4, 5/6)$.

With these new points:

$$48\int_{0}^{5/6}\int_{0}^{5/4}u \ dudv=\frac{125}{4}$$

Comment: Oh gosh, what a blunder. Thanks.